# How to add MeanSquaredLossLayer to my network

Tags: neural-networks

I would like to choose my loss function. From the references for `MeanSquaredLossLayer`, I can add it to `NetChain`, `NetGraph`, or `NetTrain`, but when I try to add to `NetChain` I get an error; when I add it to `NetGraph`, `NetTrain` will train the network, but it complains about my dataset. Finally, when I add it to `NetTrain`, I get an error.

Here is my code:

```
coder = NetChain[
           {9, LogisticSigmoid, 9, LogisticSigmoid, 1}, 
           "Input" -> 3, "Output" -> "Scalar"
        ]
 trainer = NetInitialize[coder]
 trained[dataReady]
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Can you specify what errors you get specifically, and what complaint about your data set?

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example of specifying a `MeanSquaredLossLayer` loss function:

some example data

```
data = Flatten[Table[{x, y, z} -> Norm[{x, y, z}], {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {y, -1, 1, 0.2}, {z, -1, 1, 0.2}]];
```

train net with `MeanSquaredLossLayer`

```
coder = NetChain[{9, LogisticSigmoid, 9, LogisticSigmoid, 1}, 
"Input" -> 3, "Output" -> "Scalar"];
trained = NetTrain[coder, data, MeanSquaredLossLayer["Target" -> "Scalar"]]
```

By the way, the default loss layer is the `MeanSquaredLossLayer`, so you can just omit the loss layer and just write it as

```
trained = NetTrain[coder, data]
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `NetChain` does not support any layers with multiple inputs or outputs (it would no longer be a chain). Thus you cannot put a loss layer into a `NetChain`. You have to use a `NetGraph`. For an example, see the `MeanSquaredLossLayer` documentation. One example from there:

`net = NetGraph[{ElementwiseLayer[Tanh], MeanSquaredLossLayer[]}, {1 -> NetPort[2, "Input"]}]`

You can of course embed your `NetChain` into a `NetGraph` along with the loss, and extract it again using `NetExtract` after training.

Comment: Thank You for the clarification!

Comment: @user34018, you should accept the answer so that other users knew that it addresses the issue.